# Can ip address and gateway be the same and can number of clients be increased by changing the subnet mask?

Tags: networking, ip-address

So I am a newbie just learning networking and was wondering if gateway can be same as the allocated IP address. Also, if I have to increase the number of users that connect to my router (having default mask 255.255.255.0) can I do that by changing the default mask to something like 255.255.248.0 or any other? 
Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be the same.

Yes, you can change netmask, but you need to do that on every computer/device having an IP address on the network, otherwise part of the machines in the network cannot be reached.